# Finding $a_n$ of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

There's two sequences whose $a_n$, that is, the general term for the sequence, I'm supposed to find out. Please help.

1)

{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...}

2)

{1, 1/3, 1/2, 1/4, 1/3, 1/5, 1/4, 1/6, ...}

Comment: Try to look for a pattern in the spacing of the $1$s in the first sequence. Think triangle numbers. For the second you should notice that the sequence of odd terms, and the sequence of even terms, have very nice representations, try weaving them together.

Comment: In first sequence, there seems to be no pattern at all and it keeps on oscillating between 0s and 1s, so it's safe to say that it diverges. Thanks, btw.

Comment: The sequence diverges, yes, but that doesn't mean there is no pattern. The entries with a 1 are $2,5,9,14,20,$... the first few triangle numbers are $1,3,6,10,15,21,$... The $n$th triangle number is given by $n(n+1)/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second :

We can see
$$a_{2m}=\frac{1}{m+2}\ \ (m=1,2,\cdots)$$
$$a_{2m+1}=\frac{1}{m+1}\ \ (m=0,1,\cdots)$$
So, we have
$$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{2}{n+4}\ \ \ \text{if $n\ge 2$ is even}\\\frac{2}{n+1}\ \ \ \text{if $n\ge1$ is odd}\end{cases}$$
Hence, noting that 
$$2\left(\frac n2-\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor\right)=\begin{cases}0\ \ \ \text{if $n\ge 2$ is even}\\ 1\ \ \ \text{if $n\ge1$ is odd}\end{cases}$$
we have
$$a_n=\frac{2}{n+4-3\times 2\left(\frac n2-\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor\right)}\ \ \ (n=1,2,\cdots)$$